# Need to show one random tip per day to the user

Tags: java, android

I am developing one mobile app where I have to show one tip per day if user clicks on the tip button. all the tips are defined in one text file. It reads the file and randomly pics up the tip (using `Random` of Java) and displays in the app.

Now my question is how can I restrict the app to show one tip per day. Tip should be same for the whole day doesn't matter how many times user clicks on tip button in the app.

Please provide your ideas to make it work.

Comment: Use `Runnable` thread to show `textView` per day and use `Random` class to randomize the `textViews`

Answer (score 3):

I would use a daily alarm to store the tip of the day in the shared preference of the android device. Then you can retrieve the tip of the day from the shared preference and not worry about anything else.

[Shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[Alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: I think this will be the best idea to do it....Thanks..i will try it..

Comment: Nice solution, better than regularly checking a file like my example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and map this timestamp to some picking method? maybe basing on day number in month, week or even year?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//by default it gets current time
//you might set another using setTimeInMillis(long milliseconds)
int dayNum = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

String[] tips = ... ;
int posOfTip=tips[dayNum%tips.length];
String yourTip = tips[posOfTip];
```

Comment: It will be difficult to use this sort of solution and achieve a sense of randomness. Instead, with your current code, you merely cycle around the tips. (Although maybe that's a good thing!)

Comment: true, but it's just a snippet, for "true" randomness Anjali may use some "salt" for day number picking. but then he have to saving this random position for a day like other answer suggest